# What is the symbolic meaning of Lord Ganesha's trunk?

Tags: puranas, ganesha

Some of the pictures of Lord Ganesha has trunk on left side, while in some other images, its on right side. I know that there is a symbolic meaning to it as my grandfather used to say, but i forgot. Can anyone please explain me the difference between trunk on left side versus trunk on right side?